# Python to JavaScript Persistant connection

Tags: javascript, python, networking

I have a webapp all that is communicateing with a python script via a simple HTML form(I use the bottle microframework). The problem is, creating a new request for each piece of data creates a lot of overhead.

So the question is, how can I create a persistent connection bewtween my webapp and my python program? Is there any tools or library's you would suggest?

Comment: How do you know this creates a lot overhead? Have you measured it? Also, is it possible to send more data at once so the number of requests is reduced?

Comment: The data is being used to control a robot, so the data will need to be sent as fast as possable. As for knowing that it creates overhead, I havent tested it, but based on my understanding of the http protocol, for every bit of data you send you need a opening packet, then some data packets then a closing packet. Therefore the more data you send in quick succession the more time you waste.

Answer (score 3):

If you're sure that the connection overhead really is the part which is slowing you down, then you will have to get the Python script to run as a daemon, and you'll probably want to use it by opening a WebSocket which can hold onto your persistent connections. See for example:

http://popdevelop.com/2010/03/a-minimal-python-websocket-server/

A quick search on DuckDuckGo [also](http://dev.enekoalonso.com/2010/05/22/more-websockets-now-with-python/) [turns](http://dan.bravender.us/2010/1/15/WebSocket_Games_in_Python_with_Tornado.html) [up](http://mumrah.net/websockets-in-python) [these](http://gehrcke.de/2011/06/the-best-and-simplest-tools-to-create-a-basic-websocket-application-with-flash-fallback-and-python-on-the-server-side/) [examples](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-websocket). Good luck!